# amCharts zoomToDates function does not seem to be working right

Tags: amcharts

I'm trying to use the zoomToDates function on render of an amCharts Gantt plot: http://jsfiddle.net/Lw2bhxm0/1/

```
// Doesn't appear to work right...only a few of the events are shown
chart.addListener("rendered", function(event) {
  event.chart.zoomToDates(new Date(2016, 1, 1), new Date(2016, 1, 2));
});
```

The result is much different than if I zoomed to the dates by conventional slider bars or by click and drag. Further, if I try to zoom to a date outside of the data range, it zooms to this same period with missing data. Am I using this wrong or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zoomToDates` is a categoryAxis-based function, however the Gantt chart uses a date-based valueAxis to plot dates. You have to call the chart valueAxis' [`zoomToValues`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#zoomToValues) method instead:

```
chart.addListener("rendered", function(event) {
  event.chart.valueAxis.zoomToValues(new Date(2016, 1, 1), new Date(2016, 1, 2));
});
```

**Note**: `zoomToValues` only accepts Date objects and millisecond values for a date-based valueAxis unlike `zoomToDates`, which can also accept string-based dates. You can use [`AmCharts.stringToDate`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#stringToDate) to convert string-based dates to Date objects for use with `zoomToValues`, e.g. `chart.zoomToValues(AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-02-01", "YYYY-MM-DD"), AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-02-02", "YYYY-MM-DD"));`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw2bhxm0/2/)